# api-platform : how secure custom operation

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to know how to secure custom itemsOperation with api-platform, I found this code on documentation:

```
/**
 * Secured resource.
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"method"="GET"},
 *         "post"={"method"="POST", "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"{"method"="GET","access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER') and object.owner == user"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

But I want to do something like:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "get"={"method"="GET"} //Public route,
 *     "special"={"route_name"="special", "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object.owner == user"}},
 *     "special2"={"route_name"="special2",  "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"}
 * })
 */
```

Does it work? Or I have to check user roles in special Action file?

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: I tryed your answer but voter is not call, I think I should use a listener before and then the call the voter.

Comment: The voter should be called, please check this part of the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#configuring-the-voter :)
You maybe have to defined your voter as a service with a specific tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider create a custom [symfony voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)

Please try this code, I'm here if you don't understand something with voters

```
<?php
namespace yournamespace;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;

class YourObjectVoter extends Voter
{
    const YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION = 'custom_action';

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!$subject instanceof YourObject) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return true;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if(!$user instanceOf User) {
            return false;
        }

        if($subject->getOwner() === $user) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you need to define your voter as a service with the tag **security.voter**

```
class:  Yournamespace\Security\YourObjectVoter
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

**custom_action** is the same string that the one defined in the voter class

With this code you can just secure your action with :

```
itemOperations={
 *         "get"{"method"="GET","access_control"="is_granted('custom_action', object)"}
 *     }
```

Let me know if It doesn't work. I hope it's help !

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for a POST end-point. The `object` is NULL inside the voter.